# Reoccurring Out of Office Every Other Week Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-office

In Outlook, is it possible to set a an out of office automatic reply every other week on the same day? e.g. every other Monday.

I see a solution here using headers for every week: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/set-up-recurring-out-of-office-auto-reply-for/71dd1fef-ba99-4a2b-be72-7d509e8848eb

But I would need something that goes out every other week (once per 2 weeks).

Outlook setting solution preferred, but would not be opposed to VBA.

Comment: If you have access to Power Automate (often included in Enterprise 365 subscriptions -- see if you have access to https://make.powerautomate.com/), you can use the public automation "Setup automatic replies in Office 365 Outlook on a recurring basis."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that there's no such available feature in Outlook.

Considering that you would be out of Office during that particular time(such as on Monday per 2 weeks), as a workaround, it's suggested that you could create a recurring meeting and set the status as Out of Office. Please refer to the following steps:

1.Create a new meeting > click Making Recurring, and then set what you need.

[image]

2.Change the status to Out of Office.

[image]

Hope to help you!

Comment: Darn, this is what I have but was hoping for some way to have automatic replies too. Thanks though!